# Editing Pledge Amount Deletes Payments

Tags: pledges

Since upgrading to 5.3, we've noticed that Pledge amounts can be edited, which then deletes any payments made toward the pledge.

In earlier versions, the Pledge amount could not be edited. (this is true with 4.6; I'm not sure about other versions)

The only discussion I can find is a patch from a few years ago created for 4.7: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17762

Answer (score 2):

Yes thats true, if you update certain parameters of existing pledge than it deletes all pledge payment and recreates it. Below are the parameters when changed deletes all pledge payments.

- amount
- frequency_unit
- frequency_interval
- installments
- start_date

Comment: But there's no warning for the user, which causes the uninformed to destroy contribution history. I understand it works this way, but I don't understand why it's not considered a bug or why there is no work around. (is there a work around?)

Comment: actually it should 
1. Keep existing pledge payment record.
2. Delete un-paid (pending/overdue) pledge payment record.
3. Re-calculate the number of installment based on new installment amount or frequency unit or interval change.
4. Then add new entries of pledge payment.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check this PR

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13374

There seems to be a bug that allows you to change the payment schedule and wiping out the contributions in the process. The above patch will fix the same.